# How can I get these curves in for the material

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I was wondering how to get these curves at the bottom. Is this made by masking a specific path or how would you do it?

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUi is very powerful, you can write your own buttons.

You can write something like this to made an individuel button..

```
struct BlueButton: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding()
            .background(Color(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0.5))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .clipShape(Capsule())
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button("Press Me") {
            print("Button pressed!")
        }
        .buttonStyle(BlueButton())
    }
}
```

Take a look at hackingwithswift.com - https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/customizing-button-with-buttonstyle

The solution you wish is a little bit tricky but i found a solution on youtube.
Take a look at the video ***"SwiftUI Shapes Live: 3 - The Wave"*** from ***Mark Moeykens*** on youtube and just use the "wave" on a button.

Comment: he asked about the curves at the bottom and these are buttons so I thought this would be a good solution for his problem. But okay :-)

Comment: Ah yes, I see now these are two buttons.